# Unused scenes hide temporary from Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have added several scenes to the storyboard and i have to add few more. Is there a way to hide scenes temporary. because it is hard to manage many number of scenes.

Answer (score 1):

As you split the code of the app in multiple modules,it is always good to use **multiple storyboards**, one per each module and also use independent XIBs for those view controllers that are used everywhere (in more than one module) or require specific configuration. In this way, your problem will be solved, and also, your code will be more maintainable in a team environment where multiple developers are working on the same app.